# add WCF reference server to .net core API project

Tags: .net, api, wcf, server, asp.net-core

I try to find a way to add WCF reference server to my  .net core API project with [Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService&showQnADialog=true) .But failure to add a reference to a WCF service secured with basic authentication. And that Tools doen't help to work with Certificate Authentication Options. So any help todo or any blog/ tutorial to work with WCF on .net core is welcome

Comment: Any help is welcome . :( i am currently reading oreilly-programming-wcf-services-3rd-edition-aug-2010.

Comment: .net Core doen't support WCF . So i changed back to web api 2.0 :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can retry this by installing latest version of visual studio 2017 and add proxy with [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService) extension. If latest changes will not fix your problems, plz provide more details on you service (protocol, bindings) and client call